# flutter GridView with rectangular items

Tags: flutter, gridview

I have a GridView which needs to stay a GridView because I fetch the items from an api, so it has infinite scrolling. the items are images, sometimes square, sometimes rectangular, but not mixed. how can one add a section under each image, when grid items are only supposed to be square?

childAspectRatio would not work, as image sizes can vary

Comment: Add your code snippet and current result screen

Comment: flutter_staggered_grid_view: Try using this grid view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) package.

[image]

```
AlignedGridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: 4,
  mainAxisSpacing: 4,
  crossAxisSpacing: 4,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Tile(
      index: index,
      extent: (index % 7 + 1) * 30,
    );
  },
);
```